# creating infinite loop in main thread while having infinite loops in spawned threads

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I am trying to create an infinite loop in the main ruby thread, while having infinite loops in spawned threads, but this doesn't work:

```
my_threads = []
for i in 1..2 do
    puts "Creating thread #{i}"
    my_threads << Thread.new(i) do |j|
        loop do
            sleep(1)
            puts "work in #{Thread.current.object_id}"
        end
    end
end

my_threads.each do |t|
    t.join
end

loop do
    sleep(1)
    puts 'work in main thread'
end
```

I need it this way because in my Rails app, I cannot use ActiveRecord objects inside of a thread, as explained here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24903230/activerecord-object-freezes-thread-in-multi-threaded-script

so I need a main thread that runs a loop, while having spawned threads run their own loops all concurrently.

The code above however does this:

```
work in 79515570work in 79515510

work in 79515510work in 79515570

work in 79515510work in 79515570

work in 79515570work in 79515510

work in 79515570work in 79515510

work in 79515570
work in 79515510
work in 79515570
work in 79515510
work in 79515570work in 79515510
```

It never reaches the main thread loop. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in your main thread is stopped here:

```
my_threads.each do |t|
    t.join
end
```

What [`join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Thread.html#method-i-join) does is make the current thread wait until the the thread object it is called on finishes its run.

To resolve this, simply skip the above block:

```
my_threads = []
for i in 1..2 do
    puts "Creating thread #{i}"
    my_threads << Thread.new(i) do |j|
        loop do
            sleep(1)
            puts "work in #{Thread.current.object_id}"
        end
    end
end

loop do
    sleep(1)
    puts 'work in main thread'
end

# work in 84665270
# work in 84665760
# work in main thread
# work in 84665270
# work in 84665760
# work in main thread
# work in 84665270
# work in 84665760
# work in main thread
# work in 84665270
# work in 84665760
```

Comment: So the new invocation on Thread automatically begins the work in the thread?

Comment: Also Thread::abort_on_exception = true should be enabled by default

Comment: @JohnMerlino - yes, a thread starts as soon as it is initialized.